# smooth jQuery animation of visible div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadein, fadeout, removeclass

I have a hidden div, filled with content and made visible when you click on another div. The clicked div has to fade down so the hidden div doesn't 'jump' in, it has show up like this:

1. Move down the click-div
2. Fade in the new-div

But instead the click-div moves down, then the new-div appears all from sudden and 'pushes' the click-div down. These are the important lines: my .galleryarea has to move down and the .moreinfo-div has to appear smooth.

```
    $(".galleryarea").animate({ marginTop: '200px' }, 1500);
    $("#moreinfo").removeClass("hidden", 1500, "easeInBack");
    $("#moreinfo").animate({ opacity: 1 } );
```

Really hope anyone has an idea! Also feel free to have a look at the whole fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mleyendecker/632Fw/150/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the marginTop after the animation completes:

```
$('.trigger').click(function () {
    $(".galleryarea").animate({
        marginTop: '240px' // Changed from 200 to 240 as 200 wasn't quite far enough
    }, 1500, function() {
        $(this).css('marginTop', 0) // <-- important piece
    });
    $('.dark').removeClass('dark');

    $("#moreinfo").removeClass("hidden", 1500, "easeInBack");
     $("#moreinfo").animate({ opacity: 1 } );
```